# Spatial database vs. Geo database

Tags: database, spatial, difference, geo

Do they mean one and the same.

After reading through many links & references, could not clearly spot the difference between these two.

In simple terms whats the difference between these two?

Answer (score 0):

According to [here](http://ggim.un.org/meetings/2015-ISGI-Jordan/documents/Session%203-Geodatabases.pdf) they are the same -- "Spatial databases are also called geospatial databases, geographic databases, or geodatabases."